# Azure AD SSO login problem with admin account

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, single-sign-on, openid-connect

I've registered a single application in Azure AD for the following reasons.

- Azure AD SSO (From Any Azure AD directory)
- Read users, groups, and their members

Provided following permissions and granted admin consent.

[image: Azure AD Permisisons]

NOTE: We still depend on some of the Azure AD Graph API. So, we have added the legacy API permissions.

I can able to contact the Azure AD using REST API and get the user, groups and other information.

When I try to sign in to the application from any other directory, I'm getting the following consent screen. I can able to provide the consent and proceed to log in.
[image: azure Ad consent screen from other directories]

But, when I try to login into the same directory, I'm not getting the consent screen even when I logged in with the Azure AD admin. Stuck in the following screen.

[image: Adure AD error]

When I register separate applications for SSO and REST APIs, this issue doesn't occur.

I would like to know why I'm stuck in the above screen when combining both SSO and REST API permissions.

Comment: Please check the applications's app role assignments whether the administrator has permissions to access the application data or not.

Answer (score 0):

•   Please check whether the correct Azure AD roles have been assigned to your account ID, i.e., Global Administrator, Cloud Application Administrator, Application Administrator, or owner of the app object through the as one of these is needed for you to access the application. Also, ensure that you have assigned your account ID the correct app role assignment for the admin consent to be allowed during the SSO signup process as below: -
[image: App roles]
[image: Application roles and administrators]

You can check the app role assignments for your account ID through the Enterprise application blade and searching your application there, then opening it and selecting the users and groups blade, check the app role assignment that your account ID has to that application while also, giving ‘Azure Service Management’ api permissions for user_impersonification as below, thus ensuring that you account ID will be having correct API permissions.
[image: Azure Service Management]
[image: App role assignment]

Once, the above settings are configured correctly, you should be able to access the application through your admin credentials.

Comment: Thanks for your update. I've not yet checked this solution. Will try it out this week and update.